# VBA Move Data from workbooks to one specific workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have files of sales data for each day from the last 5 years (hundreds of workbooks).

Each workbook has many worksheets, and I am looking to only take information from the summary sheet within each file.

Each file has a summary page titled "Summary Detailed" with:
4 pieces of data in cells E12, E13, E14, and E15.

I want to take this information and transpose it into rows in a new file. 
I also want it to copy the name of the workbook into Column A and put the data next to it (columns B-E).

Then I would like to take two more pieces of data from another worksheet within those workbooks and place them in the columns to the right of the 4 above (F,G).

The other worksheet is called "Daily Detailed". Since the sales tally varies every day, the total number of rows is different in every file.  But the two relevant rows are labeled "Total Pipes" and "Total Valves" (in Column B) and the data is located in the J column for both rows.

I have the files organized in folders by year, so "2014".  Is it possible to run macro to open files within the folder without having to manually open each file?

Any ideas on how to  build a macro to grab this data from each workbook?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Go through it please.....

Answer (score 0):

The bare minimum of searching this site wouldve landed you something similar to this. Check out excel-vba documentation contents (its a pretty useful resource)>>

```
 Sub Theloopofloops()

 Dim wbk As Workbook
 Dim Filename As String
 Dim path As String
 Dim rCell As Range
 Dim rRng As Range
 Dim wsO As Worksheet
 Dim StartTime As Double
 Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
 Dim sheet As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 StartTime = Timer

 path = "pathtofile(s)" & "\"
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
 Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
     DoEvents
     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, True, True)
         For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                Set rRng = sheet.Range("b1:b308") 
                For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
                If rCell <> "" And rCell.Value <> 0 Then
                   'code to do stuff
                   'avoid stuff like .copy/.paste
                   'using stuff like "sheet.range.value = sheet.range.value instead
                End If
                Next rCell
         Next
     wbk.Close False
     Filename = Dir
 Loop

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

 End Sub
```

Also part of the requirements for asking questions on this site is having at least tried yourself. Seeing in how this code is readily available already in numerous places on this site, i saw no harm in just being helpful :)

Also youll need to adjust this code to suite your needs. I did the heavy lifting for you though.